# Is there a simple-to-use Windows-10 client for Lightning Network?

Tags: lightning-network, windows

I'm having trouble finding a Windows 10 client for Lightning Network which is simple to use and which can be installed without needing to learn a lot about the underlying technical concepts.

Is there any reason why such an application program is not possible?

Comment: If you want to use lightning in a non-custodial way, there's 2 clients I find very easy to use: Electrum, Zap. If you're comfortable using it in a custodial way, then Muun wallet has by far the easiest user experience of any wallet I've ever used. Download BlueStacks, install Muun

Comment: Edit: Apparently Muun is non-custodial as well, which is amazing considering the UX it has

Comment: @hydrabeast Sorry, I have no use for any "phone apps".

Comment: I've rewritten this to focus on the core of the question. If you disagree with the change, please click the "edited..." link and select "rollback". However note that questions asking for product reviews tend to get answers based on opinions and which tend to become out of date quickly. Therefore the question may get closed if many people take that view.

Comment: I mean, Sybil has been told this before, but LND has a Windows binary…